# Regex select all text between brackets and after " : "

Tags: regex

So I've been learning regex lately and it seems I am at a roadblock with my new expression. I need to be able to select all text in brackets and set them as different groups. My expression does one of the two pairs, but how would I do multiple? Look around? I also would like to select the statement after " : " to the end of the line, and I'm not sure why this isn't working. Explanation would be great!

Example is here:
https://regex101.com/r/uV2mD3/2

---

`([\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}\s[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2},[\d]{3}).+(\b[A-Z]{2,}\b).*\[(‌​\S+)\](?:\s\:\s).+(?=\n|$)`

First group selects date/time format, second group "DEBUG" or "LOG", third and fourth should be whatever is in brackets ([]), and fifth group whatever is after " : "

Comment: Why don't you paste the expression you are trying into your post? This would create an analog record on this site.

Comment: What tool will be reading your regexp?

Comment: python style. The demo link above shows you exactly what is happening. That is why I post it. It is fairly large equation to explain without my example.

Comment: This sequence `[(‌​\S+)]` has Unicode chars in it: `\[(\x{200C}\x{200B}\S+)\]` is that intended ? .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For better readability you can use the `x` option that allows you to write a multiline regex:

https://regex101.com/r/uV2mD3/3

```
(?x) # X option
(
[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}\s* # Date
[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}    # Hour
,[\d]{3}                   # Number
)
\s+
(\w+)  # Tag (DEBUG)
\s+    # Some spacing
\[(.*?)\]\s* # First  tag
\[(.*?)\]    # Second tag
\s*:\s*
(.*)   # Last string
```

If the number of `[.*]` is known you can simply repeat the pattern in your regex for all the groups.

If the number of `[...]` is variable, this will be a much more complex regex.

You can also name you capture groups with `(?P<name>)` as below

```
(?x)
(?P<date>
[\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2}\s* # Date
[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}    # Hour
,[\d]{3}                   # Number
)
\s+
(?P<tag>\w+)  # Tag
\s+    
\[(?P<group1>.*?)\]\s* # First  tag
\[(?P<group2>.*?)\]    # Second tag
\s*:\s*
(?P<last>.*)   # Last string
```